# Launch WFP project from another in same Solution

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dotnet solution with 3 WPF projects with one being the a hub from where the other two WPF projects (and any future projects) will be launched from. At the moment I am using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filelocation)` to launch the .exe file in the bin directory of each project I want to launch. Is this the way it is supposed to be done? Many NuGet packages are shared over all projects does this mean multiple of the same package will be included when I deploy the Solution ?

Comment: `Process.Start` is likely the canonical approach, but you might also consider [registering a custom protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration) and setting your application(s) up as handlers. This would additionally allow you to ["deep link"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/windows-10-special-issue/app-integration-linking-and-integrating-apps-on-windows-10) into specific parts of the applications from each other.

Comment: Why is this multiple exe rather than one app with plugin functionality. Maybe using mef to discover dll dynamically.